# What is a SFW query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've searched around and haven't been able to find out what an SFW query. The instructions for school are-
1.  Provide the SQL code for the simple (sfw) queries to display all of the data in each of the tables you have created and populated. 
a.  Demonstrate that you have tested your code from part G1 by providing a screenshot of your results.

I can't find anything in the course material about them either.

Comment: I assume that SFW means `select`/`from`/`where`.

Comment: The opposite of a [NSFW](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=NSFW) query? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Provide the SQL code for the simple (sfw) queries to display all of the data in each of the tables you have created and populated.

I suppose it is a

**SELECT** field **FROM** table **WHERE** field = condition query

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense than what I could find.